# Form json from javascript and dynamically update the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to get the coordinates (associated with an id) from a page and store them  in a json file. User should be able to add or delete more ids.

Basically, If I right click on the page, an input field pops up - whatever I type onto the field (which is an ID) along with the x and y coordinates should be saved in a json file.

File should be in this format:

{"sensor1":{"x":121,"y":23}, "sensor2":{"x":232,"y":131} . . .}

I use context menu for right click functions and able to get the x and y coordinates (pos.x and pos.y in the code below). I need to now save these dynamically in a json file ( user should be able to  add / delete ids)

How can I create a json file from javascript and add or delete contents dynamically? Help ?

Code thus far (to get the x and y coordinates when right clicked on the page):

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.contextMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"    />

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready( function() {

        // Show menu when #myDiv is clicked
        $("#myDiv").contextMenu({
            menu: 'myMenu'
        },
            function(action, el, pos) {

            var name=prompt("Sensor Id ","Enter Id here");

            if (name!=null){


            alert(
                'Sensor: ' + name + 'Action: ' + action + '\n\n' +
                'Element ID: ' + $(el).attr('id') + '\n\n' + 
                'X: ' + pos.x + '  Y: ' + pos.y + ' (relative to element)\n\n' + 
                'X: ' + pos.docX + '  Y: ' + pos.docY+ ' (relative to document)'
                );


            }   

        });

    });

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="myDiv">
    Right click to add
     <div id='cid' class='container' style="height: 100%">
    <img src="./3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
    <li class="edit"><a href="#edit">Place</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX to send the data to the server, then it can update the file.

Comment: what's your server-side language? You need to write a little script in that which can accept an ajax request containing the data and amend the file accordingly.

Comment: php it is.. So, i do an AJAX POST to php file which will amend/edit the json as needed? Will try that